# Solving for X with matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

Solve for $X$ given that $A$, $B$, and $C$ are invertible matrices.

$$(X-B)A=BC$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Multiply the equation on the right by $A^{-1}$ to obtain
$$
X-B=BCA^{-1}
$$
Adding $B$ gives
$$
X=BCA^{-1}+B
$$
Hence
$$
X=B\left(CA^{-1}+I\right)
$$